# How to prevent the Win8 navigation panel from automatically expanding?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

The left-hand navigation panel in Windows 8 keeps expanding automatically based on my folder browsing. This requires me to constantly manually adjust it back to the default position when I want to access my libraries, download folder, etc. How can I make the menu remain in the default position?

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

This is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open an Explorer window, then `View - Options - General - Automatically expand to current folder` (uncheck). This has been around since Vista IIRC.

Please note your question is offtopic at Stack Overflow and will hopefully be migrated to the [right site](https://superuser.com/) soon.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That was the first thing I checked though, and it's been disabled all along (http://s23.postimg.org/5itjnua97/Capture.png). Sorry about having posted in the wrong area.

Comment: @user3025457 Are you sure you are not using a beta version? If not, try installing some Windows updates and/or upgrade the system to 8.1. I cannot reproduce this behaviour with the tick cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat user3025457. I just followed the registry edit at http://www.theeldergeek.com/automatic_expanding_trees_in_windows_explorer.htm (making the FriendlyTree entry and setting it to 0) and after a restart still nothing happened.

However, this time when I did the typical View > Options > ... approach as mentioned by GSerg, the box was checked and when I unchecked it, to my surprise, the stupid auto expanding finally went away. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please summarize what the instructions at the linked page say, in case it goes away in the future.